# V3137 False Positive

Tags: pvs-studio

PVS Studio throws V3137: The 'funclist' variable is assigned but is not used until the end of the function. Program.cs 13

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace V3137_False_Positive
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<(string name, Func<Task> func)> funclist;

            funclist = new List<(string name, Func<Task> func)>
                {
                    ("Test", new Func<Task>(() => Task.CompletedTask)),
                };

            foreach ((string name, Func<Task> func) in funclist)
            {
                var task = func;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a false positive?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a false positive. We'll try fixing it in one of the future releases.

Also, false-positive reports are not the entirely right format of questions for stackoverflow, so consider sending them directly to PVS-Studio support at support@viva64.com or https://www.viva64.com/en/about-feedback/.

Thanks for your feedback!